# Can you have an html list inside a <textarea> and it look like a list?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, html-lists

I tried

```
<textarea rows="10" columns="2"><li>joe</li><li>jerry</li></textarea>
```

to see if I could put an html list in a `<textarea>` but it just showed as text. Is there any way to show it as a list inside the textarea?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't have HTML inside `textarea`s - it's for plain text only. However, you *can* try using `contentEditable` for this. The result isn't very good, but you be the judge whether you want to use it or not. Simply use something like this:

```
<div class="editable" contenteditable="true">
    <ul>
        <li>List item</li>
        <li>List item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The problems with this method is that it's difficult to predict what HTML the browser will produce, and that some of the HTML produced are truly atrocious, and that you'll have to sanitise the input a lot more than using plain text. Also, the interface for this isn't specified in the specifications, so you'll be dealing with different interfaces in different browsers.

See: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/bN2tm/ and http://html5demos.com/contenteditable

Comment: What are the drawbacks to this method?

Comment: Saying you can't have HTML inside a `textarea` is a bit confusing. You can have it, it just won't be rendered as HTML.

Comment: ok, so if I am trying to have an area where text can be entered in a semi-formatted way (with lists etc.), but look good and be easily usable by non techish people who don't easily understand using things like html markup, would the be a good method to use?

Comment: @chromedude If at all possible, try using a WYSIWYM solution, like wmd + markdown used here on SO. `contentEditable` means a lot more work trying to fix browser quirks. Of course you can always go with a WYSIWYG editor, but those are abominations in my opinion.

Comment: @Yi Jiang ok, I completely agree on the WYSIWYGs they are absolutely terrible and annoying. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible.

`textarea` is for displaying and editing *text*, not HTML.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to have your HTML inside a `<textarea>` rendered as HTML.

If you want your users to be able to edit and modify the list contents you can try using a WYSIWYG HTML editor like [FCKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) or [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/).

It's a bit of an overkill if you just want the list functionality and none of the other rich text editor capabilities, but both of those editors can be fully customized an trimmed down. Check the [FCKEditor demo](http://ckeditor.com/demo) named "Custom Toobar" for an example.