# How to set the value of an WMD textarea

Tags: php, wmd, wmd-editor

When I set the value of the WMD textarea the normal way it display escaped HTML.

```
<textarea><b>kur</b></textarea>
```

this displays

```
<b>kur</b>
```

instead of  **kur**

EDIT: Ended up sending the markdown to the server and using [PHP Markdown](http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/) to convert it to **HTML** and storing both in the DB.

Are there any vulnerabilities doing it this way? 
Should I check the HTML for anything?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question, I believe you can get your answer from there.

[Can you have an html list inside a <textarea> and it look like a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095690/can-you-have-an-html-list-inside-a-textarea-and-it-look-like-a-list)

Give it a go.