# Bullets and Numbering in Textarea using Jquery

Tags: html

I am developing a page using html5. I want to show bullets and numbering only in textarea. Kindly suggest a way for the same. please do not suggest the use of iFrame as it cause some issue in mobile browsers. Any plugin in JQuery will be ok I found some but was not working in mobile due to iFrame.

Comment: How does an iFrame prevent anything from happening in a mobile browser?

Comment: Your question is also very vague. Questions on SO need to describe a specific problem, what you are trying to achieve and what you tried.
This question is more along the lines of "i don't know how to do something, find me a solution"

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095690/can-you-have-an-html-list-inside-a-textarea-and-it-look-like-a-list

Comment: hi,let me elaborate. i am trying to copy text from a div with li tags in textarea. for that i am using $('.textarea').wysihtml5();. this displays text with li styles in textarea. problem is that, when the page is viewed in mobile with mozilla browser it displays the text in textarea with li style, but the same does not work in chrome mobile browser. it does not even display the text in chrome browser.